# Change MySql row to column based on ID

Tags: mysql

I have some data in MySql, it show as random order like this:

```
╔═════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ lead_id ║ field_number ║   value   ║
╠═════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╣
║    1    ║      1       ║  Richard  ║
║    1    ║      2       ║    CEO    ║
║    1    ║      3       ║  New York ║
║    1    ║      4       ║  02/05/63 ║
║    2    ║      1       ║    John   ║
║    2    ║      2       ║    Staff  ║
║    2    ║      3       ║   London  ║
╚═════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

What's query do I have to input to make the table change into this layout:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦══════════╦════════╗
║lead_id║   1   ║   2   ║     3    ║    4   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╣
║   1   ║Richard║  CEO  ║ New York ║02/05/63║
║   2   ║ John  ║ Staff ║  London  ║        ║
║       ║       ║       ║          ║        ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

I've tried this code

```
SELECT wn3c_rg_lead_detail.lead_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 1 THEN value END) AS name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 2 THEN value END) AS title,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 3 THEN value END) AS city,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 4 THEN value END) AS date
   wn3c_rg_lead_detail.field_number,
   wn3c_rg_lead_detail.value
FROM wn3c_rg_lead_detail
GROUP BY wn3c_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
ORDER BY wn3c_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
```

But it said it doesn't correct query..

Comment: I'm afraid your current table does not contain enough relational data to generate that output.  We would need some column which tells us _which_ field numbers 1-4 correspond to which actual person.

Comment: It's effectively insoluble. You have an attribute, and a value, but no entity.

Comment: @Alfi Septandhi, is field_number real or it is fiction numbers?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've added lead_id column

Comment: @TeymurMardaliyerLennon It's a real numbers

Comment: @AlfiSeptandhi then it is easy you need simple query as below

Comment: Your updated query makes no sense and won't generate your expected output.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just copy the query you gave me and just change the table name

Answer (score 0):

A simple pivot query can generate the output you want:

```
SELECT
    lead_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 1 THEN value END) AS name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 2 THEN value END) AS title,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 3 THEN value END) AS city,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 4 THEN value END) AS date
FROM wn3c_rg_lead_detail
GROUP BY lead_id
ORDER BY lead_id
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Could you give me the query if the table name is wn3c_rg_lead_detail?

Comment: I've input this query

Comment: SELECT wn3c_rg_lead_detail.lead_id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 1 THEN value END) AS name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 2 THEN value END) AS title,
        MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 3 THEN value END) AS city,
        MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 4 THEN value END) AS date
       wn3c_rg_lead_detail.field_number,
       wn3c_rg_lead_detail.value
FROM wn3c_rg_lead_detail

GROUP BY wn3c_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
ORDER BY wn3c_rg_lead_detail.lead_id

But it said it;s not correct

Comment: Your comment is non readable and I don't understand what you are asking.  I have reasonably answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

If numbers are real then you must write simple query

```
SELECT lead_id, max(case when field_number=1 THEN value END) as name,
                max(case when field_number=2 THEN value END) as position,
                max(case when field_number=3 THEN value END) as located,
                max(case when field_number=4 THEN value END) as date
FROM `tableName` GROUP BY `lead_id` ORDER BY `lead_id` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `name`, `field_number=1` for every entry, you can also use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    n.lead_id lead_id,
    n.value name,
    t.value title,
    c.value city,
    d.value date
FROM yourTable n
LEFT JOIN yourtable t ON t.lead_id = n.lead_id AND t.field_number = 2
LEFT JOIN yourtable c ON c.lead_id = n.lead_id AND c.field_number = 3
LEFT JOIN yourtable d ON d.lead_id = n.lead_id AND d.field_number = 4
WHERE n.field_number = 1
ORDER BY lead_id ASC
```